# If $(X, Y)$ and $(X', Y')$ have the same distribution, then so do $\mathbb{E}(Y|\sigma(X))$ and $\mathbb{E}(Y'|\sigma(X'))$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, conditional-expectation

I am having trouble figuring out the proof for the following question, maybe it's because I am not familiar with the regular conditional distributions.

---

Let $X, X', Y,Y'$ be real random variables defined on a common probability space, and denote $\sigma(X), \sigma(X')$ the $\sigma$ algebras generated by $X, X'$.

Prove that if the two dimensional random vectors $(X, Y)$ and $(X', Y')$ have same joint distribution, then the random variables 
$$\mathbb{E}(Y|\sigma(X)) \quad \text{ and } \quad \mathbb{E}(Y'|\sigma(X'))$$ have same distribution.

---

I tried to use different properties of conditional distribution but have run into trouble or into a mess, then I considered Radon Nikodym theorem but could not find useful argument.

Comment: One knows that $E(Y\mid X)=u(X)$ where $u$ depends only on the distribution of $(X,Y)$. The desired result then follows from the fact that $u(X)$ and $u(X')$ are identically distributed.

Comment: @Did, Sorry for my ignorance, how can one show that $E(Y |\sigma(X))$ is a function of $X$?

Comment: As every random variable measurable with respect to $\sigma(X)$, $E(Y\mid X)$ coincides with a measurable function of $X$. What is the text you are following on conditional expectations?

Comment: @Did Thanks, I will look into this. I do not follow any textbook. Would you recommend  any advanced (second graduate course) textbook? I have Billingsley, however there were some issues with this book, so in practice I do not follow it, mostly rely on my lecture notes.

Comment: Issues with Billingsley? Such as? A congenial introduction to conditional expectation (and much more) is *Probability with martingales* by David Williams.

Comment: I have to admit I didn't really try to stick with it, and I know that it is recommended reading almost for all probability courses.  In my case, with very limited experience, given the notation and layout of the arguments I found it difficult to follow the line of though presented there, (in the time constraints that I usually have).

Comment: @Did, how do I know that I can use the same function $u(\cdot)$, for both $E(Y' | X) = u(X)$ and $E(Y'|X') = u(X')$?

Comment: Rather for $E(Y\mid X)=u(X)$ and $E(Y'\mid X')=u(X')$. Depending on your definition of conditional expectation this can be completely obvious. What is yours?

Comment: I guess I miss here something simple.  I know two def. :  either "approximation" for $L^2$ functions. Or as a.s. unique r.v. such that $E[\mathbf{1}_{A} E(Y|\mathcal{G})] = E[\mathbf{1}_{A}Y]\,, A\in \mathcal{G}$. So first def, $u(X)$ is best approximation of $Y$ in $X$ measurable functions, the other is the best approx in $X'$ measurable functions - I don't see why they should agree. Def 2,  I try $E(E[Y|\sigma(X)] \mathbf{1}_{A}) = EY \mathbf{1}_{A} $ next I want to write something along $EY\mathbf{1}_{A} = EY'\mathbf{1}_{A'}$ for some $A'$ in $\sigma(X')$ but I don't see how...  helps...

Comment: @Zoran, thanks, but I still cant see it. Sorry I am really slow on catching up here... But $A$ is not in $\sigma(X')$ so If I replace as you say I get $E[\mathbf{1}_{A}u(X')] = E(\mathbf{1}_{A}Y')\quad A \in \sigma(X)$ since $A$ is not in $\sigma(X')$ this is not the conditional expectation with respect to $X'$. What am I missing? (I know that $\sigma(X) \neq \sigma(X')$)

Comment: Starting from your comment, note that every $A$ in $\sigma(X)$ is $A=[X\in B]$ hence $E(Y\mid X)=u(X)$ if and only if $$E(Y;X\in B)=E(u(X);X\in B)$$ for every measurable $B$, that is, if and only if $$\iint y\mathbf 1_{x\in B}d\mu(x,y)=\int u(x)\mathbf 1_{x\in B}d\nu(x),$$ where $\mu=P_{(X,Y)}$ and $\nu=P_X$. Thus, the characterization of $u$ depends only on the measure $\mu$ (and on its first marginal $\nu$). Thus, if one starts from some $(X',Y')$ with the same distribution $\mu$ as $(X,Y)$, the same function $u$ works to define $E(Y'\mid X')$ as $u(X')$, qed.

Comment: ((Who is @Zoran?))

Comment: @user90793 According to your second definition, $u(X)$ is conditional expectation $E(Y|X)$ iff $$E[\mathbf{1}_{X^{-1}(A)}(X) u(X)]=E[\mathbf{1}_{X^{-1}(A)}(X) Y], \quad A \in \sigma(X)$$. Both sides in the condition above stays the same if you replace $X$ and $Y$ with $X'$ and $Y'$.

Comment: Sorry, I made a typo in the previous comment, and had to delete it.